# 2016 Community Moderator Election - Process

Tags: discussion, status-completed, election, moderators

The 2016 Community Moderator Election is now underway!

Community moderator elections have three phases:

1. Nomination phase
2. Primary phase
3. Election phase

Most elections take between two and three weeks, but this depends on how many candidates there are.

Please visit the official election page at

https://gis.stackexchange.com/election

for more detail, and to participate!

If you have general questions about the election process, or questions for moderator candidates, feel free to ask them here on meta -- just make sure your questions are tagged [election](/questions/tagged/election).

Comment: I added "  - Process" onto the title because it looked identical in the sidebar to the official election page - I think this improves the chance that users may visit both and not overlook the more important one.

Comment: update from chat "Noting - you need at least 3 candidates to nominate for the election to actually proceed."

Comment: We now have 3 candidates http://meta.gis.stackexchange.com/questions/4333/2016-moderator-election-qa-questionnaire?cb=1

Comment: @Mapperz "you need at least 3 candidates" wouldn't that be because having only two candidates for two positions would be automatic selection?

Comment: @Midavalo but moderators need to be 'voted' in by the community, but we are not in that position anymore so users can vote next week, as with 3 candidates (currently) we do not need a 'Primary phase' straight to the Election phase

Comment: Vote Now - Election Open http://gis.stackexchange.com/election?cb=1 Good luck to all candidates.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because its 2017.